# Call jquery function only when window width gets resized

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, android-virtual-keyboard

I have a function `responsive` that changes behaviour of certain elements on my website, including hiding popups etc. I call it in 2 cases:

```
$(document).ready(responsive);
$(window).resize(responsive);
```

The problem occurs on android chrome, as the virtual keyboard actually changes the height of the screen, and triggers `responsive` function, which closes my popups (some of them have text fields, making it impossible to type).

How can I prevent this from happening? I read somewhere a good point that android virtual keyboard only changes height of the screen, not a width, so I assume it would be a good idea to compare width before and after resize. So I created this function to compare the widths before and after and run `resize()` if width is different, but it doesn't work as expected, and console logs show different document widths even though I only changed the height of the screen (using chrome developer tools).

Any idea what went wrong or how can I prevent function `responsive` being launched on height change?

```
function resizeWidth() {
    var existingWidth = $(document).width();

    $(window).resize(function() {
        var newWidth = $(document).width();
        if (existingWidth != newWidth) {
            $(window).resize(responsive);
            console.log(existingWidth);
            console.log(newWidth);
        };
    });
};

$(window).resize(resizeWidth);
```

Comment: Right away, I'm noticing that you have $(window).resize() inside the function being called from another $(window).resize(). That means when the window is resized, it will create a listener for resizing of the window. I don't think that's what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you are attaching a handler to the `resize` event multiple times. One on load, then another *every* time the resize happens and `resizeWidth` is called. You should remove the handler within that function. Also, I guess you just want to call the `responsive()` function, not attach yet another resize handler when the width changes.

The main issue you have is that the scope of `existingWidth` is not low enough for it to be seen over multiple events. You could make it global, although that is generally considered bad practice. Instead you could use a `data` attribute, like this:

```
function resizeWidth() {
    var existingWidth = $(document).data('resize-width');
    var newWidth = $(document).width();
    if (existingWidth != newWidth) {
         responsive();
         $(document).data('resize-width', newWidth);
    };
};

$(window).resize(resizeWidth);
```

Comment: Fantastic, worked! I had no idea about data attribute. Thanks